# compile error CS0305 Using the generic type List

Tags: c#, sql-server, clr, csc, mscorlib

While `csc /t:library strconcat.cs` with `using System.Collections.Generic;` I get an error

```
strconcat.cs(9,17): error CS0305: Using the generic type
        'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires '1' type arguments
mscorlib.dll: (Location of symbol related to previous error)
```

The .cs code is taken from [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/#_Toc205129487): Using Common Language Runtime.
I checked [description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379563%28VS.80%29.aspx) on msdn but can't compile till now

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
[Serializable]
[SqlUserDefinedAggregate(Format.UserDefined,  MaxByteSize=8000)]
public struct strconcat : IBinarySerialize{
        private List values;
        public void Init()    {
            this.values = new List();
        }
        public void Accumulate(SqlString value)    {
            this.values.Add(value.Value);
        }
        public void Merge(strconcat value)    {
            this.values.AddRange(value.values.ToArray());
        }
        public SqlString Terminate()    {
            return new SqlString(string.Join(", ", this.values.ToArray()));
        }
        public void Read(BinaryReader r)    {
            int itemCount = r.ReadInt32();
            this.values = new List(itemCount);
            for (int i = 0; i <= itemCount - 1; i++)    {
                this.values.Add(r.ReadString());
            }
        }
        public void Write(BinaryWriter w)    {
            w.Write(this.values.Count);
            foreach (string s in this.values)      {
                w.Write(s);
            }
        }
}
```

I'm running Windows 7 x64 with `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727` as well as `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727>`
How to compile? Sorry, I am just starting with c# - I searched some other questions here on SO and those advices did not make a progress for me (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error explained in article corresponsding to [CS0305](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yshhtt9e%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) - number of type parameters don't match.

In your case you call `new List()` with zero type parameters when one is expected like: `new List<string>()` and corresponding field definition `private List<string> values;`.

Note: if you for some strange reason want non-generic version the corresponding class named `ArrayList`, but generic `List<T>` is easier and safer to use.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is as stated, you haven't specified the type which you are storing in the list. Change this section as follows

```
private List<string> values;

public void Init()
{
    this.values = new List<string>();
}
```

Generic types in C# require the type that they use to be specified in place of the `<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

System.Collections.Generic.List requires one type argument, in this case it seems to be SqlString, so change the following part of the code like this:

```
        private List<SqlString> values;

        public void Init()    {
            this.values = new List<SqlString>();
        }
```

Comment: The list is storing `string` not `SqlString`.